# Set of Two Linear Equations

Tags: calculus

Find x and y.

$$\begin{align}
|(x+4)| =4-y \\ 
|(y-4)| =x+8 \end{align}$$

Thanks for help.

Comment: These are not linear equations.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your problem with (an? the?) absolute value?

Comment: Here is one approach: Square both equations and solve for $x$. Then solve for $y$.

Comment: the graph of these are parts of two parabolas.

Comment: @abel: They can't be parabolas. You have $|x+4|=4-y$ and similarly for the other.

Comment: @copper.hat, you are aright. these are just two orthogonal rays starting from $(-4, 4)$ and $(-8, 4).$ they intersect at $(-6,0)$

Comment: @abel: Yes, that is a nice way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring

$$\begin{align}x^2+8x+16&=y^2-8y+16\\y^2-8y+16&=x^2+16x+64\end{align}$$

Then $$x^2+8x+16=x^2+16x+64$$

which gives

$$0=8x+48\text{  or  }x=-6$$

Putting this into the first equation we get $y=4\pm2$.

Squaring is not an equivalent transformation. It may add solution to the system. So, plug these into the original system.

Comment: (-6,6) does not appear to be a solution for the first equation.

Comment: NOTE: $y=6$ is not a solution since $\sqrt{(x+4)^2}=-2$ doesn't have any solutions in real numbers.So before squaring you have to add constraint that $4-y\geq 0$

Comment: Mmmmmm ... Doh!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The equation you have quoted is pair of straight lines.
[image]

The blue and green colour represents the required pair of straight lines and the intersection points have also been quoted...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For real $a,$

$|a|=+a$ if $a\ge0$  and $=-a$ if $a<0$

Clearly, $4-y=\sqrt{(x+4)^2}\ge0\implies y\le 4$

Check each case separately .